# jQuery image gallery inside a Popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-gallery, popupwindow

I just want to ask for help

http://anonymousmind.site40.net/veryint/index.html

Try to click on the gallery and click on the image thumbnail. My problem is that the popup windows position does not retain on center. It works only after you click the second time. I can't figure out whats wrong here.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) **No**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site through firebug, and I see that your div id="popup-wrap" is styled
`display: block; top: 179px; z-index: 9500; left: 646px;`

The property `left: 646px;` seems to be the initial cause for setting the image to the far right.

After I click on the image again, the pic centers itself at `left:348px;`

Hope this gives you a starting point for trouble shooting.

Comment: #popup-wrap{
 position:absolute;
    height: auto;      
    width: auto;
 min-height:100px;
 min-width:100px;
 display:none;
}

#popup{
 background-image:url(Images/Gallery/loader.gif);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 background-color:#FFF;
    height: auto;      
    width: auto;
 padding:10px;
 min-height:100px;
 min-width:100px;
 display:none
}
This is my code. Which one should I remove?

Answer (score 0):

The element 'popup-wrap' initially takes a higher left position, and next time it takes the position correctly. Find the cause for that. It would resolve the problem.

Regards..

Comment: #popup-wrap{
 position:absolute;
    height: auto;      
    width: auto;
 min-height:100px;
 min-width:100px;
 display:none;
}

#popup{
 background-image:url(Images/Gallery/loader.gif);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 background-color:#FFF;
    height: auto;      
    width: auto;
 padding:10px;
 min-height:100px;
 min-width:100px;
 display:none
}
This is my code, which one of these is the problem?